# Javascript how to plus minus var with number?

Tags: javascript

Javascript how to plus minus var with number ?

When click on `id="right_arrow"` it's will be call `function right_fn(value)`

but why in function `function right_fn(value)` not work ?

https://jsfiddle.net/d21rb3mp/2/

this is HTLM code.

```
<div class="left_arrow" id="left_arrow">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0EDajBr.png">
</div>
<div class="right_arrow" id="right_arrow" onclick="right_fn(-200)">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Zf0mFym.png">
</div>
<ul class="ul" id="ul">
  <li class="li">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ose4V9j.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```

this is javascript code

```
<script>
function right_fn(value) {
   document.getElementById('left_arrow').setAttribute('onclick','left_fn(value++200)')
   document.getElementById('right_arrow').setAttribute('onclick','left_fn(value+ -200)')
   document.getElementById("ul").style.transform = "translate3d(+value+px, 0px, 0px)";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use concatenation operator, `'left_fn(' + value + 200 + ')'`

Comment: Or `\`left_fn(${value + 200})\``

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function right_fn(value) {
  document.getElementById('left_arrow').setAttribute('onclick', `left_fn(${value + 200})`)
  document.getElementById('right_arrow').setAttribute('onclick', `left_fn(${value - 200})`)
  document.getElementById("ul").style.transform = "translate3d(+value+px, 0px, 0px)";
}
</script>
```